# Difference between cellPressed and cellClicked signals of PyQt4 QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt4

The PyQt4 QTableWidget has both cellPressed and cellClicked signals. From the name, and the little experimentation I did with them, they appear to do exactly the same thing. Is there a difference between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These signals on cells are not sharply documented (that I can find) but I'd interpret them by analogy with the `pressed`, `clicked`, and `released` signals on buttons:

**pressed** means the mouse's left button's been pressed down inside the widget,

**released** means the mouse's left button's been released (let up) inside the widget,

**clicked** means the mouse's left button's been pressed, then released (let up), both inside the widget

So if you press the button down inside the widget, hold it down, move the mouse elsewhere, and only then release the mouse's button, then you should only see the `pressed` signal, but neither of the other two; while any `clicked` signal always implies both `pressed` and `released` have also been signaled.

I believe that normal UI behavior should be to respond to `clicked` only, unless you want to do something special if the button's pressed **and not released** for a certain time (i.e., held down for a prolonged time).